# Circular References with spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, eclipse, maven, jpa

i am using spring boot for the first time and trying to change my web application to take user details(Email and password) from a mysql database(Workbench). The application is being built using maven. I am trying to do this for one user and one admin at the moment. I am trying to achieve this by using JPA. The application works fine when logging in with In Memory Details using the InMemoreyUserDetailsManager. When i delete the code that is used for the InMemoryDetailsManager and configure the application to connect to the database i get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  webSecurityConfig (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.hr.web.app.WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService)
↑     ↓
|  inMemoryUserDetailsManager defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

I can get the error to go away by adding `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true` but that does not allow me to login with the details from the database. I have run a JUnit test class and was able to add a test user to the database so i know the connection configuration is correct. Any help anybody has with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I have created all of the classes that are needed for login, this includes an entity class for user, admin and role. I have created a repository user, admin and role too. I have also created the CustomAdminDetails and the AdminDetailsServiceImpl service classes and also created these classes for user. I have added the correct dependencies to the pom.xml and added the configuration code into the application.propertes file.

Comment: If you are using Constructor based injection, try changing that to fields-based injection. Give `@Autowired` on fields. If you do that, there is no need for a constructor (a default one without any parameters will be used), and both instances will be created without any issues. Then field values will be injected via reflection in both instances. So, ServiceA can have a reference to ServiceB, and ServiceB can have a reference to ServiceA.